Windows CA - Move KDC from one certificate to another
I need to move the KDC and SmartCard "role" from present certificate to LATT-FP01-CA to get Windows Hello to work.
I'm using LATT-FP01-CA for Ubiquiti Password-less logon, so that certificate need to be there.
I have been looking at Google and all these places, without much help.
I need to delete the certificate that at present holds the KDC and SmartCard role without me completely destroy the company network.
Certificates
User Error message

I don't think you understand the purpose of these certificates. The cert issued with the Domain Controller Kerberos Authentication template containing the KDC, Smartcard and so on EKUs has been issued by your CA server to the domain controller - all domain controllers require a cert with those EKUs to service Windows Hello.

The [KDC Authentication ] OID is required for enabling authentication with Windows Hello for Business to on-premises resources by Microsoft Entra joined devices.

Note: I really, really hope you have more than one DC. All the DCs should have a cert that was issued with that Domain Controller Kerberos Authentication template.
Then you need a separate certificate for the Enrollment Agent for Windows Hello. Read further in that article linked previously about that procedure from the Microsoft side. I tried to find some Ubiquiti documentation about a KDC certificate required somewhere other than the DCs - because that is unlikely to be correct - but was unable to.
Then the clients will probably need some kind of certificate. This will depend on the product requirements. The enrolment agent will be enrolling these certs for the clients. Again, it will depend on what the product is configured to do.
In summary, do not touch those Domain Controller Kerberos Authentication certs on the DCs. Carefully read the product documentation again, because I think there's something you've skipped or misunderstand - it might help if you linked to the documentation. Finally, I highly recommend you contact the vendor to assist with the product setup if the documentation is unclear.
Also, please tag this question with Ubiquiti, since someone might be familiar with it.
